# Processing dependent elements that are in the wrong order

Tags: php

The following PHP example code only works if the "bar" elements come before the "foo" elements. If they are in the wrong order, I will get a "call to a member function on a non-object" error.

```
$data = array();
foreach($elems as $e) {
  if($e['type'] == "foo") {
    $data[$e["key"]->foo_data($e["data_foo"]);
  }
  elseif($e['type'] == "bar") {
    $data[$e["key"]] = new Bar($e);
  }
}
```

My solution at the moment is to iterate twice through `$elems`. Another solution would be to use `usort` with a custom sort function that puts "bar" elements before "foo" elements.

Are there any programming patterns or libraries that would allow me to process the elements in arbitrary order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping twice seems like the most sensible solution. Loop once to prepare your objects, loop a second time to let those objects process data. There may be an entirely different, better solution, but that's hard to say without seeing a more concrete use case.

Answer (score 0):

A practical approach would be to use an intermediate data representation that is tolerant of stuff appearing out of order, then do another pass over the data to finalize it, for example:

```
foreach($elems as $e) {
  if($e['type'] == "foo") {
    $data[$e["key"]]["foo_data"] = $e["data_foo"];
  }
  elseif($e['type'] == "bar") {
    $data[$e["key"]]["bar"] = new Bar($e);
  }
}

foreach ($data as &$d) {
    $foo_data = $d["foo_data"];
    $d = $d["bar"];
    $d->foo_data($foo_data);
}
```

A similar alternative would be to fix the data incrementally, which wouldn't require another loop but is much worse because it couples the fixup logic with your actual data extraction logic and violates DRY:

```
foreach($elems as $e) {
  if($e['type'] == "foo") {
    if (isset($data[$e["key"]])) {
        $data[$e["key"]]->foo_data($e["data_foo"]); // normal operation
    }
    else {
        $data[$e["key"]] = $e["data_foo"]; // temporary result
    }

  }
  elseif($e['type'] == "bar") {
    if (isset($data[$e["key"]])) {  // incremental fix
      $bar = new Bar($e); 
      $bar->foo_data($data[$e["key"]]);
      $data[$e["key"]] = $bar;
    else {
      $data[$e["key"]]["bar"] = new Bar($e); // normal operation
    }
  }
}
```

Finally you could of course pick some other (well-engineered) approach to avoid both looping again and writing "bad code", but PHP doesn't make that easy and you would end up writing lots of code for questionable benefit.

General recommendation: keep a temporary data representation and loop once more in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is a solution that uses a proxy pattern:

```
class BarProxy {
    private $callstack = array();
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        $this->callstack[] = array($name, $arguments);
    }

    public function createBar($params) {
        $bar = new Bar($params);
        foreach($this->callstack as $call) {
            call_user_func_array(array($bar, $call[0]), $call[1]);
        }
        return $bar;
    }
}

class BarData {
    private $data = array();

    public function getBar($id) {
        if(!isset($this->data[$id])) {
            $this->data[$id] = new BarProxy();
        }
    }

    public function createBar($id, $params) {
        if(!isset($this->data[$id])) {
            $this->data[$id] = new Bar($params);
        }
        elseif($this->data[$id] instanceof BarProxy) {
            $this->data[$id] = $this->data[$id]->createBar($params);
        }
    }

    // Other methods for getting the data, maybe implement Iterator or ArrayAccess 
}


$data = new BarData();
foreach($elems as $e) {
  if($e['type'] == "foo") {
    $data->getBar($e["key"])->foo_data($e["data_foo"]);
  }
  elseif($e['type'] == "bar") {
    $data->createBar($e["key"], $e);
  }
}
```

**Pro:** This code avoids littering the for loop with `if` statements. The classes will be in their own files, the loop stays clean and understandable. The two classes could be further abstracted to proxy and store arbitrary classes.

**Con:** This solution comes at the cost of function calls and two additional classes, so the performance and memory consumption is probably worse than just looping twice.